# Automatically add end tag when typing xml start tag?

Tags: xml, eclipse, autocomplete

I am using Eclipse 3.7.2, when editing a XML file and typing e.g.

```
<test>
```

I would expect Eclipse to automatically add

```
</test>
```

but it doesn't. Is this the default behaviour? Is there an autocomplete option for XML I can enable?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you haven't correctly set XML editor. You should set default XML editor. 
Go to eclipse settings in:

```
Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations
```

and choose default editor for XML files (*.xml) from existing associated editors list suitable for XML syntax. Mark that, if *.xml file type isn't showed you should add that entry by own.

If it won't work you can use XML plugin, for example: [Rinzo XML](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/)

You can also choose editor for file from package explorer. For that click right on file and:

```
Open with
```

then choose suitable editor.

Comment: I couldn't find a suitable editor, so I installed Rinzo XML and I am now using it - great! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, if you type `</` eclipse autofills the end tag for you.

Comment: not working for me, but I am now using Rinzo XML, so problem solved ;-)